# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I am new to Laravel. I am trying to create a laravel CRUD with resource controllers. However, when I try to run `php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and
>   table_name = migrations)

Here is my database.php

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'design'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

and this is my env file:

```
    APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:hLJn+XHKPjf5qEvROeyMMLIjw56Kg9RkXhZIlbjjne4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=design
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

This is a common problem and I have tried many solutions but they wont work. Please help.

Comment: I have never used homestead but normally db port is 3306 , are you sure your db credentials are correct ?

Comment: Originally I tried with 3306 but after reading some answers I changed it to 33060

Answer (score 1):

try to use PORT 3306 and change localhost to 127.0.0.1

for example

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE= 
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: originally it was 3306 and was still giving me the same error. I changed it according to the solutions I found on  the net

Comment: On changing the local host to 127.0.0.1 I get the following error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'172.20.0.1' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)`

Comment: Your new error msg is pretty clear - you are using the wrong username/password.

Comment: `DB_HOST` should be changed to db container name